# How to move scene camera to coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Ok so I zoomed really far out and went a long way out, and now I cant find where everything i was working on went. I feel like such an idiot and I just want to know, it there any way to find it? I know the scene coordinates to the location i just want to know how to move my scene camera there. I'm sorry if this question has been answered or if it makes no sense, I'm just really stressed right now. Also if this helps I'm un unity 2d.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select a GameObject in the 'Hierarchy' window that you want to focus on with the scene view camera.
2. Select the 'Scene' view window
3. Press 'f'. The scene view camera will now move to and focus (you can remember this by that the f key stands for focus) the selected GameObject.

You can read more about scene view nagivation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html)

Unity documentation on scene view navigation:

> To center the Scene view on a GameObject, select the GameObject in the Hierarchy, then move the mouse over the Scene view and press F. If the GameObject is already selected, F zooms in to the pivot point.

Comment: I have tried this and it works. Thank you so much, I was really stressed that I lost everything. Thank you.